# Strings Equals Methods difference

Tags: java, string

I'm reading a Java magazine and the autor use the `intern()` method to compare Strings.

```
String ns;
String erg; 

if( ns != erg.intern() ) {
    System.out.println("is not equals");
}
```

I never heard about this method. I'm always using `equals` instead.

```
if( !ns.equals(erg) ) {
    System.out.println("is not equals");
}
```

When should I use `intern()` and when `equals`? or are they the same?

Comment: Basically: don't use .intern(); more often than not it's not worth the trouble

Comment: I don't think this is the same question. @user3232446 [`intern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) uses a pool of strings. Basically don't use it. It is not obvious what your intentions are and it has a bunch of gotchas, where as `equals()` is obvious.